# Two request in the same thread with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, multithreading, spring-boot, concurrency

Anybode knows the way to receive two requests in **the same thread** with Spring Boot?

More specifically:

I have a Spring Boot API which receive a request and I send a response. At this moment, the thread finishes.

What I want next, is that the thread waits until the SAME thread gets another call (and then do things with the request...)

Is it possible?

**EDIT:**

I need the data from first request, to do things with that data mixed with the data from second request.

Comment: That isn't possible. What is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Why do you need that? Use Spring Webflux in that case.

Comment: edit with the need.

Comment: Then let the data from the first request be send again with the second request. Or store it in the session or somewhere else for retrieval later.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that something is wrong about your architecture/desing of the API, because your case is quite weird... However one thing comes to my mind - Use Session mechanism (Spring Session) to share the data between TWO requests.

- block Thread A (first request) and constantly check if required data is in session data
- if Thread B (second request) will come - put data to session - it will unblock Thread A for processing

Comment: Probable yes but I think It could be solved with a static hasmap, created in the context and reuse in the rest of application.